# Are the fluentbit filter plugin filtering step by step?

Tags: filter, fluentd, fluent-bit

Are the fluentbit filters filtering step by step? How it works actually?

When the first filter eliminates some data, will the second filter make another elimination from the first filtered data?

Could the second filter modify with all logs or with excluded data from first filter?

[FILTER]
Name  kubernetes
Match kube.*
Kube_URL https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
Kube_Tag_Prefix kube.var.log.containers.
Exclude Namespace_Name=unwanted-namespace

[FILTER]
Name modify
Match *
Copy kubernetes_pod_name host

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each filter will read the output from the previously executed filter